# Installing apk from sd card is successful, but the app shuts down when started

Tags: android, apk, android-sdcard

I saved my app to the sd card and installed it from there to test in app billing. It was installed but when I tap on it to start it, the logo splash plays and the app shuts down. How can I know what is the problem? Is there a way to debug it?

**Edit:** it works fine when run with Eclipse

Comment: Many be , see your phone logcat for error.

Comment: Does it just shut down? Or does it give an error?

Comment: @Md Abdul Gafur Where is phone logcat?

Comment: @MarkBuikema no it doesn't. it just shuts down

Comment: connect your device to computer and run your app, see logcat error to find out what is the problem

Comment: Search Internet "see android application log"

Comment: Do you have android development setup with you? if yes then please open eclipse and in that you can see Logcat screen. Connect your phone   by enabling USB debugging mode from Settings->Developer option. And run your application.

Comment: @Ankit it works fine when run with Eclipse

Comment: Do you mean work well in Emulator?

Comment: I mean when run from Eclipse on my real device

Answer (score 0):

**First** , enable the `debugging` mode in your application `Manifest` in `application` section as following:

```
 android:debuggable="true"
```

**Second** , connect your device with your laptop or PC and open the `LogCat` screen and make sure that you are opening the application `workspace` and the `Eclipse` can see your application from the `DDMS` screen (You will see your device and the package name of your application under it).

**Third** , open the application and your `Crash` and exception will be printed on the `LogCat`.

you can also add manual `log` lines to track your app progress as following:

```
Log.d("Key", "Message");
```

I hope it helps

Comment: hey I did like you said. Added debuggable true to the manifest. Exported signed apk again and copied the apk to my device. Deleted the old app and installed the new one. Opened Eclipse and started the app, I cannot see the app in the DDMS under my device. And no Log.d messages are printed.

Comment: From the `DDMS` section open the `devices` tab, you should be able to see your device (if you are enabled debugging mode from the device setting). Under it you will see a lost of your debuggable apps listed by `packageName`. Select your with the mouse and monitor the `logcat`.

Comment: yes i know what you mean. my device is active, but underneath there are no apps